# htaccess rewrite to point subdomain to subfolder on same host

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, dns

I am trying to create an htaccess rewrite that points (not redirects) a subdomain to a folder on the same host. I have three subdomains that need to be pointed to three folders. It's important that the URL remains as the subdomain but displays the content of the subfolder.

https://live.example.com point to https://example.com/live/

The closest answer I've been able to find is this one:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Host} ^(?:live\.example\.com)?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/live/
RewriteRule ^(.*) live/$1 [NC,L,NS]
```

But for some reason, this isn't working. I'm not sure if I'm placing the .htaccess file in the wrong place, or if there's something incorrect about the syntax/code.

Comment: Syntax is fine, that rule _should_ work. So these are the points you need to verify: 1. DNS resolution of those subdomains, do those requests really reach that http server? 2. does that http server really respond that those subdomains? 3. how is the http host for those sub domains configured, what `DOCUMENT_ROOT`, is it really the same as for the main domain? 4. is the rewriting module enabled at all inside that http server? 5. is the consideration of such distributed configuration files (".htaccess") enabled at all for that location?

Comment: ... 6. did you _really_ place that ".htaccess" file in the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` that is configured for all the http hosts relevant here? 7. Did you _reallly_ name that file ".htaccess" (and not ".htaccexx.txt" for example)? 8. Is that file actually readable for the http server process? 8. Does your http server's error log file contain anything of relevance to your test requests? 9. Are you really not looking at client side cached results from earlier attempts?

Comment: And a general question: what does "isn't working" actually mean? _Exactly?_ No rewrite get's applied? A wrong rewrite? Do you get a result? Which is? Do you get an error? Which? Please use the "edit" button below your question to revise it and add more information to your question. Do _not_ add additional information here in the comment section. Answer the questions above, add that information and how you obtained it to the question itself.